# Repeating a block of html like a function

Tags: html, content-management-system

I am learning html, css and content management by building my own personal site, but I have very little experience in any of these areas. One thing that has bothered me is the amount I have to repeat a segment of "html code". For example, on my site I may have a block that looks like:

```
<div class="talk">
  <a href="link">
    title
    <div class="info">
      subtext
   </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

where `link, title` and `subtext` are the only elements that change. As a programmer, this looks like a function with three arguments: `talk(link, title, subtext)` and I would implement this by keeping a separate text file or database with all the entries and a program to "compile" the data and the HTML formatting into a final product. In fact, this is what I do now with a simple python script and BeautifulSoup. I have a feeling though, that there are tools out there for *exactly* this sort of thing, but there are *so many options* and systems I not even sure what I'm looking for exactly (Grunt, bower, Ruby on Rails, SASS, HMAL, handlebars, ...). This is not a request for recommendations, an acceptable answer could involve any framework, but I prefer simplicity over power.

What is canonical/standard way to do this? What is a minimal working example using my code block above?

Comment: While possibly warranted, a down and a close vote are not very constructive without a comment. Please help me improve this question or ask for more clarification if you think it is unclear.

Comment: Any server-side language like PHP will do. That's the most common and practical way of generating redundant contents. The usual way is to have a web server running the script languages, but nothing prevents you from using most of them as offline compilers. (and the downvoter wasn't me, btw).

Comment: The short answer is no. There is no native html support to replicate chunks of code. You'll need a preprocessor. There are many options as you said.

Comment: You can use a CMS as well if you are unhappy building your own code. I recommend wordpress, expression engine or concrete5.

Comment: @badAdviceGuy I see, I hadn't considered the difference between rendering server or client side. Though not in the scope of the FAQ at SO, can you suggest any standard preprocessors? The suggestions can seed my own searching.

Comment: @Hooked it really depends on how you want to approach the problem. As others have mentioned PHP is a great help with this, but there are other options. Task runners like Gurnt are another. There is always the client side JS templates way. Underscore.js is a good place for small scale applications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you asked for a live example, here is one in PHP:

#### news_print.php

```
function output_some_news ($link, $title, $subtext)
{
    echo
"<div class='talk'>
     <a href='$link'>
         $title
        <div class='info'>
            $subtext
       </div>
     </a>
 </div>";
}

// this is just for show. Usually the data come from a database or data file
$topics = array (
    array ("http://celebslife.com", "Breaking news", "Justin Bieber just grew a second neuron"),
    array ("http://nerds.org"     , "New CSS draft available", "We won't be forced to use idiotic lists to implement menus in a foreseeable future"));

function output_news ($topics)
{
    foreach ($topics as $topic)
    {
        output_some_news  ($topic[0], $topic[1], $topic[2]);
    }
}
```

And from within your HTML page:

#### news.php

```
<?php include 'news_print.php'; ?>

<div class='news'>
    <?php output_news($topics); ?>
</div>
```

As for using PHP as a preprocessor, it is pretty straightforward:

```
C:\dev\php\news> php news.php > news.html
```

will produce pure HTML from your PHP script.

The PHP engine will be invoked from the command line instead of a web server, and its output will be stored in a file instead of being sent back to a browser, that's all.

Of course you will have some differences. For instance, all the web-specific informations like caller URL, cookies, etc. will not be available if you use PHP offline. On the other hand, you will be able to use command line arguments and environment variables.

Comment: Thanks, this is a nice example for me to learn and build off of.

Comment: Welcome to the exciting world of web programming :)