# Making footer in one page for whole website

Tags: php, html, css

I am new in PHP. Is it possible to make footer in one file and whole website will share this single file, so that If I want to change a website footer. So I make change in only one file so whole website footer changes automatically. 
Here is sample of code of my footer :

```
<footer>
<!-- Here will be markup -->
</fotter>
```

Comment: Yes it is possible with PHP.

Comment: Nearly perfect duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336484/repeating-a-block-of-html-like-a-function)

Comment: A small typo there - `</fotter>` should be `</footer>`!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes its possible you can do this in many ways : 
I always prefer by making function. (It will help you to understands PHP more)

**footer.php**

```
<?php
 function place_footer()
 {
?>
  <footer>
   <!-- Here will be markup -->
  </fotter>
<?php
 }
?>
```

**file.php**

```
include('footer.php');
```

and at the end of file just call

```
<?php  place_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: If all you are doing is outputting HTML, you don't even need the PHP function...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, create a php file called footer, this file looks like:

```
    <footer>
    <!-- Here will be markup -->
    </footer>
```

At the bottom of each page do a PHP include:

```
    include('footer.php');
```

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Put your footer code in a separate file, then in the page you want to add it to use the following code:

`<?php include('includes/footer.html'); ?>`

(In this case the file is in a folder called 'includes' in the same folder as the main file. In that folder is footer.html)

If your main page is all PHP, you can leave out the  tags.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Create your footer in one file like so:

**footer.php:**

```
<footer>
    <!-- Here will be markup -->
</fotter>
```

and then include it in all of your other files:

**index.php:**

```
        ... some mark-up ...
        <?php include_once('footer.php'); ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why `</body></html>` outside the footer?

Comment: @RahilWazir I guess you could have them in your footer. It's a little more modular if you leave them out. That way a page could possible not load the footer but still have valid markup. Either way should work fine...

Answer (score 1):

You can actually cheat the system to add a footer to all pages, without the need to actually add it to every file.

Firstly, find a file that is global and loads on `ALL` pages. Normally a config file, settings file or database connection.

If you have a globally called file, you can use a class to do it all for you, using the `__destruct` attribute.

In the global file, add the contents of the code below;

```
class globalFunctions
{
    function __destruct()
    {
        echo '<footer>
            &copy; 2013 - Site name.
        </footer>';
    }
}

$globalFunctions = new globalFunctions;
```

Beats editing lots of files, when you can just add this.

PS: This also appends the page, to include the footer, if you use `exit;` or `die()` functions.

Comment: What if I want to place footer in a simple static page, without involving your class. Too much for that.

Comment: You're arguing an irrelevant point there, Sir. The post specifically makes the point that it is for a site with more than one page in the following sentence snippet: `Is it possible to make footer in one file and whole website will share this single file`. It is also void on the basis that if you had a single static page site, it would prove pointless to even include the footer when, for one page, you may as well continue with the standard HTML format.

My solution offers a fast way to solve the problem -- no adding to all files, just the initial global file.

Comment: In one point right, assume you have to pages you need to include footer, and do I want to initiate your global class in every page? I hope not. It makes sense only if other pages are served through one.

Comment: Maybe my problem is the fact I learned PHP whilst playing with MMORPGs, so my solutions apply to game systems with multiple pages, all interlinked with global classes and whatnot. Regardless, a question was asked and I gave it an answer - it's up to him to know if it's a suitable suggestion for his system, not ours.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is no necessity to create a function for it. Simply create a php file called `footer.php`

```
<footer>
   My Company 2014
</footer>
```

Then use php built in function `require_once` wherever you want.

`require_once('footer.php');`

Answer (score 0):

If your footer DOES CONTAIN PHP CODE (and the file is "footer.php"), then at the end of every php page, write following one line of code:

```
<?php include_once 'footer.php'; ?>
```

However, if your footer is just a normal text file (such as, "footer.txt") and DOES NOT CONTAIN ANY PHP CODE, then it will be slightly faster if you use this code instead of the above shown:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents('footer.txt'); ?>
```