# Need help turning a block of HTML & PHP into a variable/function I can call at will

Tags: php, html, variables

I have made a personal website I am using for my vinyl collection. I have blocks of code (HTML & PHP) I am currently wrapping into a PHP variable so I can call it at will on different pages. What I've noticed, is that when a PHP variable is nested inside another variable, it is not parsed. I am searching for a way to take a block of code, wrap it up, and be able to call that code elsewhere. This is what I have right now:

```
<?php $gdclock ='
<div class="container"> 
  <a href="img/12/GD/clock-a.jpg" data-lightbox="main" data-title="<?PHP print $inf[1];?>"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-a.jpg" class="image" onerror="imgError(this);"></a>
  <div class="pressing">First Pressing</div>
  <div class="total"><div class="outof">PRESSING OF</div> 1000</div>
  <div class="album-colour">Black (Clock Face Labels)
   <div class="more-images">
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-b.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-b.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-cover.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-cover.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-back.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-back.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-insert.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-insert.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
'?>
    
<?php print $gdclock; ?>
```

I am calling the entire block with $gdclock, but the $inf[1] variable I have nested does not work. I realize that nested variables inside other variables is a no-no, but the $inf[1] is large and I am doing it this way to keep the code cleaner looking.

My question is, how can I take this chunk of HTML with the PHP, and be able to print it out in a similar method to what I am doing? I hope I have explained this well enough!

Comment: You could use an [include file](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), or put your code in a function.  There are plenty of examples and tips in other questions here, eg searching for "*php repeat code blocks*" turns up many relevant results ([here's one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21336484/repeating-a-block-of-html-like-a-function)).  I'd suggest starting with some tutorials to get familiar with these ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe look into heredoc syntax

[heredoc manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

```
    $gdclock =<<<GDCLOCK
    <div class="container"> 
        <a href="img/12/GD/clock-a.jpg" data-lightbox="main" data-title="{$inf[1]}"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-a.jpg" class="image" onerror="imgError(this);"></a>
        <div class="pressing">First Pressing</div>
        <div class="total"><div class="outof">PRESSING OF</div> 1000</div>
        <div class="album-colour">Black (Clock Face Labels)
         <div class="more-images">
                 <a href="img/12/GD/clock-b.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-b.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
                 <a href="img/12/GD/clock-cover.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-cover.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
                 <a href="img/12/GD/clock-back.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-back.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
                 <a href="img/12/GD/clock-insert.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-insert.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
         </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    GDCLOCK;

    echo $gdclock;
```

Comment: This syntax is brand new to me, but wow, it did EXACTLY what I needed. Thank you so much for this answer!

Answer (score -1):

`$gdclock` is unecessary.

Please try this.

```
<div class="container"> 
  <a href="img/12/GD/clock-a.jpg" data-lightbox="main" data-title="<?PHP print $inf[1];?>"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-a.jpg" class="image" onerror="imgError(this);"></a>
  <div class="pressing">First Pressing</div>
  <div class="total"><div class="outof">PRESSING OF</div> 1000</div>
  <div class="album-colour">Black (Clock Face Labels)
   <div class="more-images">
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-b.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-b.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-cover.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-cover.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-back.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-back.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
       <a href="img/12/GD/clock-insert.jpg" data-lightbox="main"><img src="img/12/GD/tb/clock-insert.jpg" class="image-bar" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.remove();"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you suggest OP repeat this on many pages, as specified in the question?